# unimplemented: unexpected ast of kind ltgt_expr in C++

Tags: c++, unix, cmake, makefile

I am trying to build a program that was written in C++ by a previous student. I use `ccmake` and then `make` to build the program. However, after I hit `make`, I am getting the error message:

```
/workspace/arthur/Project/src/DirectoryName/name.cpp: In member function     ‘void seed::Sweep(Datareg3&)’:
/workspace/arthur/Project/src/DirectoryName/name.cpp: sorry, unimplemented: unexpected ast of kind ltgt_expr
/workspace/arthur/Project/src/DirectoryName/name.cpp:confused by earlier errors, bailing out
make[2]: *** .. Error 1
make[1]: *** ..Error 2
```

The error is occuring at the last line of the code below:

The code for this source file is below:

```
#define sgn(x) ((x)>0 ? 1 : ((x)<0?-1:0))

void seed::Sweep(Datareg3& reg3)
{
    u_int i, j, k;
    Range resp;
    float min, max, t;
    float gradz;
    float grad1xa, grad1xb;
    float grad1ya, grad1yb;
    float grad2xa, grad2xb;
    float grad2ya, grad2yb;
    int keepflat, *keepflat_y;
    keepflat_y = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*reg3.dim[0]);
    for(k=0; k<reg3.dim[2]-1; k++)
    {
        ..
        for(j=0; j<reg3.dim[1]-1; j++)
        {
            keepflat = 1;
            for(i=0; i<reg3.dim[0]-1; i++)
            {
                resp.MakeEmpty();

                // top
                if(i == reg3.dim[0]-2)
                {
                    if(keepflat && keepflat_y[i])
                    {
                        // reached end at a flat.. add the edge values
                        min = max = reg3.getValue(i+1,j,k);
                        if((t=reg3.getValue(i+1,j,k+1)) < min)
                        {
                            min = t;
                        }
                        if(t > max)
                        {
                            max = t;
                        }
                        resp += Range(min,max);
                    }

                    // do we need to set keepflat_y[i]?
                    gradz = reg3.getValue(i,j+1,k+1) -
                            reg3.getValue(i,j+1,k);
                    grad2xa = reg3.getValue(i+1,j+1,k+1) - reg3.getValue(i,j+1,k+1);
                    grad2xb = reg3.getValue(i+1,j+1,k)   - reg3.getValue(i,j+1,k);
                    grad2ya = reg3.getValue(i,j+1,k+1) - reg3.getValue(i,j,k+1);
                    grad2yb = reg3.getValue(i,j+1,k)   - reg3.getValue(i,j,k);
                    keepflat_y[i] = (sgn(gradz) != 0 &&
                                     ((sgn(gradz) == -sgn(grad2xa) && sgn(gradz) == sgn(grad2ya))
                                      ||
                                      (sgn(gradz) == -sgn(grad2xb) && sgn(gradz) == sgn(grad2yb)))); 
//error occurs AT THIS LINE
```

I've never seen this error before and when I tried to do a google search for it, I got very few results. Anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: What compiler are you using, and what version?

Comment: I already counted the parenthesis, and it's correct. I am using gcc/4.6

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you simplify the expression to help out the compiler:

```
const int sgn_gradz = sgn(gradz);
keepflat_y[i] = (sgn_gradz != 0
                 && (    (sgn_gradz == -sgn(grad2xa) && sgn_gradz == sgn(grad2ya))
                      || (sgn_gradz == -sgn(grad2xb) && sgn_gradz == sgn(grad2yb))
                    )
                );
```

Another idea would be to split the compound expression into smaller expressions, using temporary `bool` variables:

```
const bool sgn_gradz_eq_neg_sgn_grad2xa = sgn_gradz == -sgn(grad2xa);
keepflat_y[i] = (sgn_gradz != 0
                 && ( sgn_gradz_eq_neg_sgn_grad2xa   && sgn_gradz == sgn(grad2ya))
                      || (sgn_gradz == -sgn(grad2xb) && sgn_gradz == sgn(grad2yb))
                    )
                );
```

By splitting up a compound expression into smaller expressions with temporary variables, the compiler will generate an error on a specific expression rather than the entire line.

Another item to do is to verify that the `sgn` function has a declaration in this translation unit.

Comment: I tried those 2 suggestions, but both of them give the same error as in the OP. As for the `sgn`, I forgot to include the line where it is defined. I edited the OP to reflect this